# ambiguity of understanding SMAPE

Tags: keras, forecasting

I have implemented several regression forecast approaches and now I want to compare them. I picked the MAE, RMSE and SMAPE ratings. My result looks like follows:

1. Approach 1: MAE= 0,6 , RMSE= 0,9 and SMAPE 531
2. Approach 2: MAE= 3,0 ,RMSE= 6,1 and SMAPE 510
3. Approach 3: MAE= 10,1 , RMSE= 17,00 and SMAPE 420

When I plot my predictions and compare them with my test set, I can see that Approach 1 > Approach 2 > Approach 3. This is also evident from the values of MAE and RMSE. But I thought that the lower the resulting SMAPE, the better the prediction.

Did I misunderstand SMAPE?
Since there is no predefined method in phyton, my SMAPE calculation looks like this:

```
def smape(A, F):
    return 100/len(A) * np.sum(2 * np.abs(F - A) / (np.abs(A) + np.abs(F)))
```

Or is the calculation wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay maybe the method was wrong.. instead i used this one from Kaggle:

```
from numba import jit
import math

@jit
def smape_fast(y_true, y_pred):
    out = 0
    for i in range(y_true.shape[0]):
        a = y_true[i]
        b = y_pred[i]
        c = a+b
        if c == 0:
            continue
        out += math.fabs(a - b) / c
    out *= (200.0 / y_true.shape[0])
    return out
```

[URL](https://www.kaggle.com/c/web-traffic-time-series-forecasting/discussion/37232)
now my results look more plausible from SMAPE compared to MAE and RMSE